# Lost console when EC2 ssh is logged out

Tags: ssh, java, screen, console

I run a java application as a server on a EC2. But as I loose my ssh connection all console messages are also lost. When I redirect all messages to `> my.log` and then use `tail -f my.log` I dont get the `e.printstacktrace` messages. I wonder what I can do.

Is there something simple that I can do, to relogin to ssh, find out which console the java application is throwing out all the messages.

So instead of doing a `java myapp.jar &`, I now do a `java myapp.jar`, so that I dont loose any console messages.

The other question is, Is there a better command than `> my.log` that does not miss any message from my application, so that I can log, and do a `tail -f my.log` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a terminal multiplexer - screen being the best known, and [tmux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html) being a more recent implementation of the idea. I use tmux, and would recommend you do to.

Basically tmux will run a terminal (or set of terminals) on a computer. If you run it on a remote server, you can disconnect from it without the terminal dying. Then when you login in again later you can reconnect, and see all the output you missed.

To start it the first time, just type

```
tmux
```

Then, when you want to disconnect, you do `Ctrl-B d` (ie press Ctrl-B, then release both keys, and then press d.

When you login again, you can run

```
tmux attach
```

and you will reconnect to tmux and see all the output that happened. Note that if you accidentally lose the ssh connection (say your network goes down), tmux will still be running, though it may think it is still attached to a connection. You can tell tmux to detach from the last connection and attach to your new connection by running

```
tmux attach -d
```

In fact, you can use the `-d` option all the time. On servers, I have this in my `.bashrc`

```
alias tt='tmux attach -d'
```

So when I login I can just type `tt` and reattach. You can go one step further if you want and integrate the command into an alias for ssh. I run a mail client inside tmux on a server, and I have a local alias:

```
alias maileo='ssh -t mail.example.org tmux attach -d'
```

This does ssh to the server and runs the command at the end - `tmux attach -d` The `-t` option ensures that a terminal is started - if a command is supplied then it is not run in a terminal by default. So now I can run `maileo` on a local command line and connect to the server, and the tmux session. When I disconnect from tmux, the ssh connection is also killed.

This shows how to use tmux for your specific use case, but tmux can do much more than this. This [tmux tutorial](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/) will teach you a bit more, and there is plenty more out there.

Comment: Billiant, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: works like a charm. I am trying to figure out why my mouse scroll wheel wont work on tmux.

Comment: @Siddharth Yes, the mouse won't work with tmux. Instead you have to do `Ctrl-A [` to enter scrollback mode. You can then PgUp and PgDown. When you're done, press `q` to go back to normal mode. (And feel free to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems if you want to leave the process running when you disconnect and see all the output later.

#### Capturing Error Messages

One problem with your approach is that you are only redirecting stdout, but not stderr, so error messages will not go into the file. The standard idiom to redirect all output is:

```
java myapp.jar 2>&1 > myapp.log
```

[This explains what 2>&1 means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21) and [this gives chapter and verse on bash i/o redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

If you want to see the difference, you could do

```
java myapp.jar > myapp.log 2> myapp.err
```

#### Leave process running when you disconnect

Even running in the background (by appending `&` to the command), a process is still attached to a terminal. When the terminal dies, all subprocesses will be killed, including those in the background.

To keep them alive you can

- keep the terminal alive despite losing your connection by using a terminal multiplexer (see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/163805/150) or,
- use [nohup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nohup.1posix.html) which will keep the command running (by ignoring SIGHUP).

To use nohup, redirecting all output to a log and putting it into the background, you can just do:

```
nohup java myapp.jar 2>&1 > myapp.log &
```

[More about nohup](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html).